# Tableau - How to make parameters available outside iFrame

Tags: jquery, tableau-api

We have a view in Tableau. This view is then embedded in an iFrame. The view has various tabs and various dropdowns. All these are parameters.

We have a link within the view, which when clicked will take the user to a page where they can add comments against the very specific view they're on e.g. which tab they are on and what selections they have made in the dropdowns

My question is rather than this - is there anyway the parent page can capture this information after the user makes the selection? The link the user currently gets redirected to is similar to this:

http://domain.com/comment.asp?URL=http://tableau/views/VIEW_NAME/LandingPage&params=SOMETHING=THAT,THIS=ELSE,ABC=123

The script then looks at the params querystring and processes that data against "LandingPage"

Alternatively - if there's a better way to capture user comments for a specific view (I realise that "view" can mean various things here!) then I'm all ears

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Frame you can get the querystring from the child-url by JavaScript using:

```
<iframe src="example.de" name="myFrame"></iframe>

var queryString = window.frames['myFrame'];
```

e.g. if the selection will be present in the url you can get it by that code.

after that, you can parse the querystring via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately it's not present. Seems to be an issue very specific to Tableau at this stage